# why my user is not save inside the group , my data is displaying out side the group

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have a issue. I store data inside the group i create whatsapp group. Now I add user inside the group, but my user data is display out side in firebase Realtime .

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                GroupRef.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                        .setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    GroupRef.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                                            .setValue("Saved").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        AddMemberRequest.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                                                                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                            AddMemberRequest.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                                                                                                        .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                                        @Override
                                                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Member Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    });
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
}
```

i just want to store store users inside the groups

Comment: What do you mean by "why my user is not save inside the group"?

Comment: i create a group know i add user in my group but my user is store out side